# Blending peeled raw whole fruits (unfiltered) v. eating them whole?

Tags: discussion

How can I make [Blending peeled raw whole fruits (unfiltered) v. eating them whole?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/103795/68642) on topic pls? Even if 1 is too subjective, 2 is objective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest first posing your question as a complete sentence. For example, "What is the best way to liquify fruit?" Then in your comments you can say, "I have a hard time eating whole fruit as pieces get stuck in my teeth, and want to blend it into juice. I have been using a Vitamix, but I'm curious if there's a better way to blend fruit smoothly without heating it up so much, which changes its flavor."

Questions that are subjective, like, "Why does blended fruit taste better than whole fruit" should be avoided. But you could ask something like, "Does blending fruit intensify the flavor or sweetness?" The way differently processed foods are tasted is part of food science. Cooks spend a lot of time working on flavor and "mouthfeel" (not to be confused with "moth-feel," which is illegal in some states). But whether one preparation tastes better than another is subjective. I may prefer apples to apple sauce, but you may not. Neither of us is right.

Your last question, "Why do liquefactions differ from eating them whole" is much too broad. That's like saying, "Why is a toilet different from a sink?" Try to ask very specific questions that can be answered directly without necessitating clarification questions from other users.